# Performance issue when json encoding nested relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm fetching data from a database using Laravel's (5.2) Eloquent ORM like so:

```
$orders = Order::with([
    'customer',
    'items',
    'items.product',
    'items.product.shop' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'title']);
    }
])->get();
```

*Note: the reason why an order is not tied to a single shop is that orders may contain items from multiple shops. Each item references the ordered product, which in turn has a reference to the shop it belongs to.*

This works fine, however, when I want to return the result to a view and render it there, it takes a long time to `json_encode` it.

I confirmed that `json_encode` is indeed the bottleneck, if I just execute the query and immediately die afterwards, the response is almost instant. However, if I do a `$orders->toJson()` (or `json_encode($orders)`) after the query, I experience the same delay in response as with returning the result to the view.

Apparently the problem lies in the (too deeply?) nested property of `items.product.shop`, if I remove that, the call to `json_encode` doesn't induce any performance issues.

Here's a sample output of a single order:

```
{
  "id": 71,
  "total_sum": "5.88",
  "customer": {
    "id": 68,
    "first_name": "One Large",
    "last_name": "Men's"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 105,
      "quantity": "1",
      "price_single": "1.2",
      "price_total": "1.2",
      "color_id": "6",
      "size_id": "5",
      "order_id": "71",
      "product": {
        "id": 149,
        "name": "Men's",
        "shop": {
          "id": 109,
          "title": "general test"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you remove the custom select from the `shop` loading does it make things any quicker?

Comment: No, the reason it's there is actually because I thought that some properties in `shop` (like `description`) may cause the performance issue because they contain a lot of text. However, selecting only two properties doesn't help.

Comment: I can also do `dump($orders);` just fine, the performance problem only arises once I introduce `json_encode($orders)`

Comment: Have you tried doing `json_encode($orders->toArray());`? I'm not sure that it will make a big difference, but I have had issues with eloquent models that were fixed by using to array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit, I have an additional attribute in my `shop` model (added via `$appends`) that gets calculated by using a nested for-loop.

Apparently still fast enough when working directly on shops, but since in the above example each order has several items and each item references a shop, performance degrades.